# How could I make my display monochrome?

Tags: display, xcalib

Let's say I want to simulate on old monochrome gas plasma display on a current-day Ubuntu installation. That could be something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di9OQLiwbIU

How could I do this? I'd mean making everything monochrome.

Answer (score 1):

here, there is something to try:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125257/how-can-i-make-the-screen-black-and-white
They say that you can add following lines to the xorg config file

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "greyscale configuration"
    Defaultdepth 8
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 8
        Visual "GrayScale"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Please tell me if it works for you

Comment: @victor jung Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this breaks X for me; the system doesn't launch graphically at all with this configuration. In case it helps, I'm using Intel HD Graphics 5500.

Answer (score -1):

Using *Cool-Retro-Term*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bugs-launchpad-net-falkensweb/cool-retro-term
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cool-retro-term
```

[image]

Comment: Cool-Retro-Term is indeed awesome. However, what I'm looking for is changing *everything*, rather than having just a single application that appears monochrome. Imagine something like this: http://i.imgur.com/lsGd2vO.png